# Yslow Cookieless Domain

Tags: .htaccess, yslow, cookieless

I have a Concrete5 site which already has a bunch of contents and I want to point the images to my cookieless domain without replacing the urls.

I created an htaccess that will redirect all images from my main site to the cookieless domain

```
http://www.example.com/images/header.jpg

to


http://static.example.com/images/header.jpg
```

It's actually working but YSlow doesn't seem to honor this. It's still giving me a low score on that part.

Comment: If cookies are for `.exemple.com` they are send for `static.example.com` too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't change the image links, browsers will still make a request to the original URL and will send the cookies. That's probably why YSlow is still giving you a poor score for that.

To properly change it you would need to:

1. Change all links to the new cookie-less domain (static.example.com)
2. Change cookies to be issued for www.example.com only (per Croises comment above)
3. Remove the redirects for images

It's a lot of work to achieve, and depending on your site traffic it may not be worth it. Like all YSlow rules (and those from other tools), it's important to understand the recommendations. Not all of them are worth the effort for all websites.

Reference: [Cookie-less domains best practices](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free)

Comment: Thank You BrianC

I guess I should have started doing this since the beginning so I wouldn't have to re-write hundreds of URL's.

Lesson learned.